# How to merge tables from 2 databases in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 - just a standard edition. Sorry if this is a rather basic question, but I know very little about SQL

I have 2 databases I've previously created using Visual Studio that would now benefit from being merged. By merged I mean copying the tables from the 2nd database to the first and deleting the 2nd database.

Is there a simple way of doing this through the SQL Management Studio?

Comment: What kind of merge ? You want to have tables from one into the other database ?

Comment: You need to provide more info. Such as are you wanting to permanently merge them? Or just with a query so you can use them merged somewhere else?  What is the structure of each table like? etc

Comment: @Simon - yes exactly that

Comment: @JoshWeatherly - the 2 databases were created separately but can logically be merged to form a single database. One has around 30 tables, the other 20 - I would like to copy the 20 tables over from database 2 to database 1 (schema and data), and delete database 2 permanently.

Comment: You can use the SQL Server Import Wizard to copy the tables from Database 2 to Database 1. Right click on Database 1 in SQL Server Management Studio, Tasks -> Import Data, then go through the steps in the wizard (source, target) until you reach a step that allows you to select the tables you want - you can select all the tables in Database 2 and where they will go to in Database 1 (they will default to their current names). See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209%28v=sql.105%29.aspx for more info.

Comment: @dash First of all thanks mate for this wonderful answer . But in my case  it is something different . I have 2 database having same schema . I want to merge the data/records from DB1.table1 to DB2.table1 .I am getting error in validation . Please reply here or to my ID - vivek.drock@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to read data from one database and merge it into another.

For example:

```
USE DBToMergeInto;

INSERT INTO TableToMergeInto
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET
    ('SQLOLEDB', 
     'Trusted_Connection=yes;Server=192.168.1.1\ServerToMergeFrom',
     'DbToMergeFrom.dbo.TableToMergeFrom')
```